# Echo messages from a script run by Puppet

Tags: bash, puppet

I am writing a bash script that will be run by puppet by an Exec resource (I know. It is not ideal). I would like to know if is possible create debug messages in the script. Normally in Bash I use echo and in a manifest I use notify. But echo seems not work when the script is executed as an Exec resource in Puppet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the documentation here for the `logoutput` attribute: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-logoutput

You can always see the output from your `echo` in the script during Puppet agent execution with `logoutput` set to `true`.

For example:

```
exec { '/bin/sh script.sh': logoutput => true }
```